# AC input not matching DC output

Tags: power, ac, dc, conversion

I know this might sound stupid but it has me stumped. I am trying to calculate the average AC power input required for a few electrical devices which will be connected to a generator.

The issue I'm having is:

AC Input - 100 ~ 240V @ 2.5A - So the maximum power draw is: 240 x 2.5 = 600W
DC output - 19.5V @ 6.7A - So the maximum power draw is: 19.5 x 6.7 = 130W

Even if you take into account the power loss (standard is 80% efficiency) - What am I missing here?

The power input does not come close to the power output?

Comment: Maybe inrush current?

Comment: `240V @ 2.5A` and `19.5V @ 6.7A`.... is that what you measured?

Comment: Where did you find those numbers? I am guessing those are the numbers written on the AC-DC converter? I think the 2.5A is the maximum current, not the average. It may even take inrush into account. Those numbers NEVER match up with the output power. And even if they did, they would only tell you the input power under max load. Really, the best way to handle this is to measure the actual AC current with a device similar to the "Kill-a-watt". Alternatively, if you know the average output power, you can use your 80% figure to estimate the actual input power.

Comment: Don't assume the average output power is 130W. It probably is much lower than that.

Comment: The numbers came from the converter. Yeah, I did some searching and looks like sometimes on the Input they put the maximum for the converter itself, not the maximum device draw. I was just after a rough figure, so decided the best way would be to assume maximum output and work backwards to find the AC current draw side. I know its rough but I just needed a rough figure.

Answer (score 1):

For a switching power supply the maximum current will occur when the AC voltage is at its **lowest** value hence, expect the maximum power (ignoring power factor effects) to be 100 x 2.5 = 250 watts. Then of course the value stated on the label will represent a worst case scenario and not a typical situation.

If the output is rated at 130 watts then typically the input power will be about 15% to 20% higher at maybe 160 watts.

Power factor can make \$V_{RMS}\$ x \$I_{RMS}\$ appear too high in terms of watts and this also possibly contributes to your misunderstanding.